# Multiple Interval Selection in JList

Tags: selection, jlist

I want to have multiple selections ("columns") from a JList. How do I get the String values of all selected items in the JList and put them in an array/ArrayList of Strings once a ("Export") button is pressed?

I have this in my constructor:

```
public ColumnList(String[] allColumns) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    listModel = createListModel(allColumns); // contains all the columns
    list = new JList<String>(listModel);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
    exportButton = createExportButton(exportString);
}
```

And in the same class is this inner class:

```
class ExportListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String columnName = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
        selectedCols.add(columnName); // add to array list
    }
}
```

Now I know this does not work. This will only work to one selected value. How do I do it for multiple selections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ExportListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String[] columnsSelected;
        columnsSelected = new String[list.getSelectedValuesList().size()];
        columnsSelected = (list.getSelectedValuesList()).toArray(columnsSelected);      
    }
}
```

I was able to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use JList.setSelectedIndices(int[]) after calling JList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION)

```
jList.setSelectionMode(
        ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    int[] selectIndices = {0, 3};
jList.setSelectedIndices(selectIndices);
```